# Vertical and horizontal scroll bars appearing for video on large screens

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where once the screen starts getting to a certain width, the video starts to grow past the height and width of the browser, and horizontal and vertical scroll bars appear. I've been struggling for hours trying to figure out how to fix it. Is there a way to keep the video full width and height on larger screens without overflowing?

You might not be able to answer this if you aren't on a screen big enough (although if you are good with dev tools, you can mimic a larger screen).

Here is a link to the [full screen codesandbox](https://vszv9.csb.app/), and here's a link to the [codesandbox editor code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-morning-vszv9?file=/index.html).

I'll also include my code here, but it won't be much of use with Stacks built in editor and browser.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  height: 4em;
}

.player-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <nav></nav>

    <div class="player-group">
      <video>
        <source
          src="http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm"
          type="video/webm"
        />
      </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what size you want the video to be? Should the whole video show within the viewport (in which case forget the cover)? On a narrow viewport do you want it to fill the whole width and just use whatever height it needs to fit? On a wide viewport do you want it to fill the whole height and just take whatever width it needs to keep its aspect ratio? Is it certain that the aspect ratio is always 16/9?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove nav tag.
2. Remove .player-group -> padding-bottom and add height property

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>

    <style>
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        margin: 0;
      }

      nav {
        background: black;
        height: 4em;
      }

      .player-group {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="player-group">
      <video>
        <source
          src="http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm"
          type="video/webm"
        />
      </video>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Unfortunately, I am attempting for the video to scale down and keeps its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav {
      background: purple;
      height: 4em;
    }
    
    .player-group {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }
    
    video {
      display: block;
      object-fit: contain;
      max-width: 100vw;
      max-height: 85vh;   /* value depends on nav height */
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav></nav>

  <div class="player-group">
    <video controls name="media">
        <source
          src="http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm"
          type="video/webm"
        />
      </video>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```